# How to specify English path alias for Chinese?

Tags: i18n-l10n, tokens, path-aliases

I created a node of type `Post` in English, and translated it using Entity Translation to Chinese, Traditional. I then set the path alias for the content type to be `[node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:title]`, so it will create an URL alias based on the menu trail and the node title.

However, for Chinese, it is coming up with the Chinese node title, is there anyway to make it display the English title instead? Possibly using Tokens?

I am aware of the [Transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module, but I am not looking to transliterate, but use the English title altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `[node:title]`, use `[node:menu-link]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[node:source:title]` instead of `[node:title]` as shown below in all translated languages:

`[node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:source:title]`

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the Chinese text still shows up on the URL.